# Starting Docker Container With Different Parameters

Tags: docker

I run docker container with the following command.

```
#docker run -it --name mydocker -v /local/path:/docker/path random_docker
```

Then I stopped it.

```
#docker stop mydocker
```

If I start the same container now with 'docker start' then It will be started with the same command I used to run this container initially.

```
#docker start mydocker
```

But I want to start the same container with different parameters/command for example with one more drive to mount like /newdrive/data:/docker/data. 
What is the possible way to modify the command?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible. But there is a way to obtain it, by commiting your container:

```
docker commit CONTAINER_ID new_image
docker run [new parameters] new_image
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change a limited set of parameters with `docker update`. Adding Volumes is unfortunately not possible.